# Montar query SQL em Python3 a partir de dados em um dicionário

Tags: mysql, sql, python, python-3.x, interpolação-de-string

Estou tentando formatar uma `query` e deixa-la desta forma:

```
INSERT INTO users('username', 'password') VALUES ('meuusuario', 'minhasenha')
```

Mas está me retornando com `[]`:

```
INSERT INTO users(['username', 'password']) VALUES (['meuusuario', 'minhasenha'])
```

Minha função no memento está assim:

```
def insert(self, table, data):
    query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + str(list(data.keys())) + ") VALUES (" + str(list(data.values())) + ")"

    return query
```

A chamada está assim:

```
data = {
    'username': 'meuusuario',
    'password': 'minhasenha',
}

print(database.insert('users', data))
```

Obs: é uma classe.

Comment: Utilize `", ".join(minha_lista)` ao invés de `str(minha_lista)`.

Comment: Já ouviu falar de [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)?

Comment: Coloca como resposta, funcionou amigão.

Comment: Já ouvi falar sim, e nessa altura do campeonato, eu não to ligando pra isso. É pra meu uso apenas. Então da nada, mas vlw @VictorStafusa heuheuhe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Python há várias formas de manipular strings e interpolar variáveis, e concatenar várias strings com `+` é a pior delas.

O seu erro é que a representação como string de uma lista - `str(list(...))` necessariamente inclui os `[ ]` - você tem que usar métodos de manipulação de strings pra montar a representação correta. Mas antes disso, algumas considerações

## Montando os valores das queries

Mas, a parte disso, quando fazemos queries, se tentamos montar o texto de SQL concatenando as strings nós mesmos, dams margem a ataques de "SQL Injection" - se os dados que são usados no SQL tem uma fonte insegura (um campo na interface de usuário, por exemplo), podem ser inseridas sequências de caracteres que realizem outras queries e comandos no banco de dados que os pretendidos.  A maneira de evitar isso é "sanear" todo e qualquer dado que vá ser usado pra compor uma query. Fazer isso certo não é trabalhoso, mas fazer *Certo* e *em toda parte* dificilmente é o que acontece.

A abordagem do Python então é fazer com que a própria chamada dos drivers de banco de dados (o método `execute`) para rodar queries no SQL seja responsável por incluir os dados vindos de variáveis na query. Assim, você não usa nenhuma das formas de concatenar strings do Python - e sim, uma marcação específica do driver de SQL.

Existem 3 - e apenas 3 - sintaxes diferentes para esse interpolação - só que como você não diz qual driver de SQL está usando, não tenho como passar qual a sintaxe exata. Mas uma delas, por exemplo, a que é usada para o SQLite, para argumentos posicionais, simplesmente é colocar um `?` nos pontos em que as variáveis substitutas serão usadas.

Nesse caso, seu código ficaria assim:

````py
conexao.execute("INSERT INTO users('username', 'password') VALUES (?, ?)", (
'meuusuario', 'minhasenha')) ```
````

Perceba que o "meuusuario" e "minhasena" são passados numa tupla, no *segundo* parâmetro para o "execute". E que a chamada `execute` inclusive insere os `'` necessários - eles não são necessários no texto da query.

Outros drivers de SQL usam em vez do `?` as marcações `{}` e `%s` para a substituição -

## montando as queries em si

Agora, no seu exemplo, você quer montar queries dinâmicas usando não só valores variáveis, mas também nomes das colunas e até nomes das tabelas.

Nesse caso, a formatação de queries do método `execute` não faz a interpolação - ela é limitada às sessões de uma query SQL onde entram valores mesmo. (Ou seja, com o método acima não dá pra colocar nomes de colunas ou tabelas dinâmicos).

Nesse caso, você pode usar a melhor forma de interpolação de strings disponível no Python que são as `f-strings` - (existem só a partir do Python 3.6).

Com as "f-strings" você coloca o prefixo "f" antes das aspas, e dentro da string usa `{}` para delimitar expressões em Python que são executadas como código - e a representação de string do resultado desse código é colocada naquele espaço.

Evitar SQL injection continua igualmetne importante, então é necessário sanear todos os parâmetros - **não se deve negligênciar isso**, nem acreditar que uma outra camada do seu software, que vai ser desenvolvida em outro momento faz isso. Aplicações em Python tem um registro recorde de segurança de falhas de injeção de SQL, justamente por que desde o começo da linguagem se adotou a prática de sanear os parâmetros justamente no momento de montar a query.

Não há uma forma universal de sanear os parâmetros de forma genérica, que valha para todos os drivers de SQL - mas se fizermos isso para os caracteres `\` `;` `'` já evitamos  problemas, então é melhor ter uma funçãozinha separada pra fazer isso:

```py
def escape(name):
    # O prefixo "r" é pra evitar que a '\' seja consumida pelo próprio parser do Python
    escape_chars = r"\';" 
    for char in escape_chars:
        name = name.replace(char, rf"\{char}")
    return name

...
def insert(self, table, data):
    e = escape  # encurta o nome da função de escape
    columns = [e(colname) for colname in data.keys()]
    insert_seq = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(data))

    query = f"INSERT INTO {e(table)} ({', '.join(columns) }) VALUES ({insert_seq})"
    return tuple(data.values())
```

E quem chamar esse método recebe *dois* parâmetros de volta - um com o texto da query, e outro com o segundo parâmetro a ser passado para o execute - o uso fica assim:

```py
    query, arguments = self.insert(table, data)
    self.conection.execute(query, arguments)
```

Note que para fins de simplificação eu usei o `%s` como placeholder para argumentos do SQL, que é o usado pelo MySQLdb - mas isso varia dependendo do driver de SQL. O módulo de driver de SQL, seja o sqlite, o psycopg, mysqldb, ou qualquer outro, tem um parâmetro `paramstyle` que define qual o tipo de placeholder a ser usado - (e alguns exigem que os argumentos sejam passados como um dicionário mesmo) - então isso tem que ser adaptado. A tabela completa (e demais especificações de métodos e atributos presentes em *todos* os drivers de SQL) está aqui: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle

---

Para fins de deixar a resposta completa, é interessante você entender o uso do método `join` das strings em Python que é feito acima - ele é o contrário do  `split`: basicamente ele recebe um objeto iterável como parâmetro, (cujos itens devem ser todos strings) e "cola"  a string inicial como separador dos itens - ou seja:

`", ".join(["abc", "def", "ghi"])` vira `'abc, def, ghi'`. E podemos colocar uma "generator expression" que processa elementos do iterável dentro da chamada do join - o que é feito acima para escapar todos os elementos.

Comment: Eu estou usando `MySQLdb`, e estou tentando concertar esse negócio de SQL Injection, eu não iria fazer isso, mas vou fazer sim euheuheu, o meu problema é com a logica pra separar as coisas, transformar os valores do dicionarios  em `?` e depois destransforma-los para passar na tupla do execute, sacas?

Comment: Pronto  -a continuação da resposta está aí - vou só ajustar para o que o MysqlDb usa em vez do `?`

Comment: Pronto -  com mais uma garibada na função dá pra deixar ela mesma achar o tipo de parametro do driver e montar a string sempre correta para qualquer conector - mas não vou fazer isso agora - o importante agora é você entender as formas de interpolar string do Python, e não usar `+`  - que tem que ser usado em Javascript pela falta de uma bilbioteca padrão e um objeto string rico.

Comment: Show sua resposta! deu certo comigo, e além de conseguir fazer, aprendi sobre algumas coisas. Obrigado man