# Conexão Tkinter - Banco de dados

Tags: mysql, python, banco-de-dados, tkinter

Boa noite! Pessoal, estou iniciando no mundo da programação e hoje estava seguindo um tutorial que pra mim não funcionou e eu não sei como resolver o problema, ja tentei de tudo. Trata-se de definir uma função de um botão que envia os dados de uma tela de login para o banco de dados. Segue abaixo:

```
def Armazenar():
    nome = NomeEntry.get()
    email = EmailEntry.get()
    usuario = UserEntry.get()
    senha = PassEntry.get()
    Db_Login.cursor.execute("insert into usuarios(Nome, E_mail, Login, Senha)
    values(?, ?, ?, ?)", (nome, email, usuario, senha))
    Db_Login.conexão.commit()
```

## Criando Botão Registro

```
RegistrarButton = ttk.Button(RightFrame, text="Registrar", width=35, command=Armazenar)
```

Quando clico no botão da função, apresenta os seguintes erros:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\celio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

File "C:/Users/celio/PycharmProjects/TKINTER/INDEX.py", line 66, in Armazenar
    values(?, ?, ?, ?)""", (nome, email, usuario, senha))

File "C:\Users\celio\PycharmProjects\cursopython\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 168, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)

File "C:\Users\celio\PycharmProjects\cursopython\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 147, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; O driver "pymysql" usa a sequência `%s` (ou %d, %f, etc...) para inserir argumentos nas queries, e não `?`. Troque os `?` por `%s` que vai funcionar.

**Explicando** A linguagem Python tem uma especificação de como os drivers de SQL, para qualquer banco de dados, devem funcionar, a [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) - essa especificação fala por exemplo, que todos tem que ter a chamada `connect`, que o objeto de conexão tem que ter um método `.execute`, que é o que executa as queries e etc... No entanto essa mesma especificação deixa livres umas 5 ou 6 formas diferentes de como é feita a marcação dos parâmetros que serão substituídos nas queries.

O "sqlite3" que acompanha o Python usa simplesmente pontos de interrogação - `?` - como está agora no seu código. Só que o `pymysql` usa a marcação com `%s` (como a usada para substituições em strings com o operador `%`, que por sua vez usa  a mesma notação do `printf` da linguagem C).

Nessa outra resposta que escrevi esses dias falo mais sobre isso:
  [Montar query SQL em Python3 a partir de dados em um dicionário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398921/montar-query-sql-em-python3-a-partir-de-dados-em-um-dicion%c3%a1rio/398930#398930)

(em particular, de interessante para o caso, o driver tem uma variável chamada "paramstyle" que diz qual é o tipode marcação esperada para os argumentos das queries - confira em https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)

[Montar query SQL em Python3 a partir de dados em um dicionário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398921/montar-query-sql-em-python3-a-partir-de-dados-em-um-dicion%c3%a1rio/398930#398930)

Comment: Obrigado Jsbueno! Resolvido.